# Unable to establish secure connection with the server ActiveDirectory

Tags: ldap, forms-authentication

i m trying to enable FBA mode in my sharepoint.
Followed all tutorials from msdn and blogs. but i am still not able to make it working.
here is how my web.config looks like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://sharepoint2" />
</connectionStrings>

<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/login.aspx" />
</authentication>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>


<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="cn=sharepoint2\administrator" connectionPassword="*******" enableSearchMethods="true" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

please help me to resolve this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens? Any errors?

Comment: this is the error which i get when i try to login as admin of site `Unable to establish secure connection with the server (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\****\web.config line 123)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
   <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
         applicationName="adtest"
         connectionUsername="cn=actualUser"
         connectionPassword="actualUsersPassword"
         connectionStringName="LocalAD">

   </add>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: same error :( i used "/" instead of "adtest in applicationName

Comment: Check your LDAP string connectons

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your connection string needs to be a little more specific (point to a container with users in it). However, it sounds like you're not even getting that far. Try removing the 'cn=' from the connectionUsername attribute (i.e. make it <*domain*>\<*username*>).

Comment: i tried it. but same error :(